# Merge two binary trees in C

Tags: c

I am trying to merge two binary trees and this is what I have come up with. I believe that my Insertmerge functions are correct as well as my and merge functions work...I am having trouble with my merge helper. I need to do is post order, left then right, but I am not sure if what I am doing makes sense. Any thoughts?

```
  SparseNode * mergehelper(SparseNode* C_array_1, SparseNode * array_2)
        {
          if(array_2 ==NULL)
            {
              return(C_array_1);
            }
        C_array_1= SparseArray_InsertMerge(C_array_1, ((array_2->left)->index),((array_2->left)-

>value));
    C_array_1= SparseArray_InsertMerge(C_array_1, ((array_2->right)->index),((array_2->right)->value));

    }

    SparseNode* SparseArray_InsertMerge(SparseNode * array, int index, int value)
    {
     check(array);

      if(array ==NULL)
        { 
          return SparseNode_create(index, value);   
        } 

      if((array->index)==index)
      {
        if(array->value == -value)
          array= SparseArray_remove (array, array->index);
        else
          array->value += value;
        check(array);
        return array;
      }    

     if((array->index)>index)
        {   
          array->left = SparseArray_insert(array->left, index, value);  
        }      

      if((array->index)<index)
        {
          array->right = SparseArray_insert(array->right, index, value);
        }  

      check(array);
      return array;
    }

    /*
    post order traversal
    new insert for merge
    adapt for nonoverwriting

    do a tree traversal
    then add the node into the copied list in the work of the tree traversal

    in merge. copy array1. call mergehelper with copy. 
    in helper. if null return, then insert left and insert right. print function is similiar
     */

    SparseNode * SparseArray_merge(SparseNode * array_1, SparseNode * array_2)
    {
      SparseNode*Arr1_copy = copy(array_1);
      Arr1_copy =  mergehelper(Arr1_copy, array_2);
      return (Arr1_copy);
    }
```

Comment: Are these binary **search** trees? Because if so all you have to do is traverse through the elements of one tree and add them to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to merge two binary trees is to simply use the functionality that the trees already provide:

- a traversal, extracting the values.
- a means of inserting values.

So the solution then becomes (pseudo-code):

```
def mergeTrees (tree1, tree2):
    valuePtr = tree2.getFirst();
    while valuePtr != NULL:
        tree1.addNode (valuePtr->value)
        valuePtr = tree2.getNextAfter (valuePtr)
```

Following that, `tree1` will then be a merge of the two trees and you can do what you want with `tree2`.

Now that's the *basic* idea - you may want to handle things like duplicate removal or error conditions, but it should be a good enough start to get you going. There's often little point in using the internals of a data structure when the published interface gives you a cleaner way.